# Ошибка чтения строки из TFileStream - читается слишком много

Tags: delphi

Может кто обьяснить что за бред творится с чтением строки из потока?
Нерабочий код(читает больше чем нужно):

```
Function ReadStrFromStream(st:TStream):string;
Var
  c:array of Char;
  b:Integer;
Begin
  st.Read(b,2);
  SetLength(c,b+1);
  st.Read(c[0],b);
  Result:=PChar(c);
End;
```

Рабочий код:

```
Function ReadStrFromStream(st:TStream):string;
Var
  c:array of Char;
  b:Integer;
Begin
  st.Read(b,2);
  IntToStr(b); //<< Нафик это надо?? вывел опытным путём что без этой строки код рабает некорректно, а именно читает из файла больше чем нужно.
  SetLength(c,b+1);
  st.Read(c[0],b);
  Result:=PChar(c);
End;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде ошибка - неопределеноое поведение. Так как вы не приводите дополнительных подробностей, предположу, что читается более 65535 байт. Объяснение:

```
Function ReadStrFromStream(st:TStream):string;
Var
  c:array of Char;
  b:Integer; // Неинициализированная переменная, содержит 4 байта мусора
Begin
  st.Read(b,2); // Замещаем 2 младших байта, в 2 старших остается мусор
  SetLength(c,b+1); // Выделяем овер 65к байт ...
  st.Read(c[0],b); // Читаем овер 65к байт ...
  Result:=PChar(c);
End;
```

Добавление `IntToStr(b);` неким образом влияет на расположение значений в памяти, случайным образом это расположение вам помогает - 4 мусорных байта нули.

Answer (score -1):

Для строк есть TStringSteam. А на щот сабжа... может Update (компилятора/студии) поможет...

ПС Integer - 4 а не два байти, используйте Word если надо два.

Comment: в курсе что он 4 байта) update который?) в потоке не только строки, там много разных типов данных хранится